# Want to use jqueryUI for Jersey response 

Tags: jquery-ui, xslt, jersey

I am a newbie to java rest resources.

My job is to get the xml documents using the rest api and apply xsl transformation .Then display the result in the accordion panels using jquery .

**I have successfully transformed the xml documents** but the output is not being displayed in the accordion panels it is being displayed in the normal form.

I have included the jquery includes in cdata section of my XSL ...

How do I get the data into the accordion panels? I'm using `@Produces("text/html")` in jersey

I've used servlets and it worked but there is a problem with jersey...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are calling your rest api through a jquery.ajax or jquery.get call?
If that's the case, then you need to render the result coming back from the server in your accordion. Rendering means doing something like

$("selector_where_I_want_to_put_my_content").html("html I want to show");

The html you want to show will be computed from the cdata section of what's coming as a response from your REST call.

Comment: Actually iam not using any jquery call .I type in the url with pathparms and query params in the browser .

Comment: no ... i dont use anything ...iam directly calling the jersey servlet with the url typed in the browser

Comment: ok I see. Then why do you put jquery-ui as a tag? The browser won't use it but will just display the text returned by the call. In Jersey, did you set the return type as text or application/xml?

Comment: webUrl ->calls jersey servlet->resources -> transformationfactory class(takes xml and xslt)->returns xhtml in the form of stream -> display the output stream on the browser .....overview of my call

Comment: I have set it as text/html and i want to use jquery ui scripts for the output returned by jersey

Comment: you may use developer tools in chrome to see more precisely what's happening.

Comment: anyways i got the solution i have changed the base url !!GOT it ....thanks for trying :)